# How to see generated source on firefox quantum?

Tags: firefox

I ask here because it's full of developers and so maybe someone has figured it out. Since Quantum, the developer tools extension (plugin) does not have the 'view generated source' tool. The firefox dev tools never had one, as far as I know. So what chance do we have now to see a full page generate source? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found a work around for Firefox thanks to Ben Pleysier at the Adobe forums.

Select all (Ctrl / Cmd A) and right click to "View Selection Source".

Comment: Doesn't work in FF 62, I still get the original source.

Comment: Works with me in FF 63, Linux 64 bit.

Comment: Only getting original source in FF 66 on Mojave

Comment: Works with FF 76 on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

If you select part of a web page and conext-click, you'll see a context menu item labeled "View Selection Source", that behaves just like "View Page Source", except you only see the source for the selection.

Comment: How's your solution different from @Dr Madvibe's solution above?